# How many ways to assign 7 different jobs to 5 different people assuming one person must have at least one job?

Tags: combinatorics

This is what i got so far.

Case 1: one person get 3 jobs and everybody else (4 people left) get 1 job. And there are 5 ways to pick a person to assign 3 jobs

$\binom{7}{3} \cdot 4!\cdot 5 = 4200$

Case 2: two people get 2 jobs and everybody else (3 people left) get 1 job. And there are $ \binom{5}{2} $ way to pick 2 people to assign 2 jobs out of 5 people

$\binom{7}{2} \cdot \binom{5}{2} \cdot 3!\cdot \binom{5}{2} = 12600$

So the total number of ways = 16800

Is that correct?

Comment: 7=1+1+1+4=1+1+2+3=1+2+2+2

Comment: Sorry, it is 5 people. Let me update

Comment: @hxthanh is there a way to direct messaging you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the people are $A,B,C,D,E$

The jobs can be broken up as
either $\;2-2-1-1-1\;$ or $\;3-1-1-1-1$

But that will only account for distributing them in order to $ABCDE$, so we need to permute the assignments between people, too, thus

$$\binom{7}{2,2,1,1,1}\cdot\frac{5!}{2!3!} + \binom{7}{3,1,1,1,1}\cdot \frac{5!}{1!4!}$$

which can be simplified in permutation form ignoring $1!s,0!s$ to

$$\frac{7!}{2!2!}\frac{5!}{2!3!} + \frac{7!}{3!}\frac{5!}{4!} = 16800$$

Comment: what is $$\binom{7}{2,2,1,1,1}$$ ?

Comment: @SeanNguyen: $\dbinom{7}{2,2,1,1,1}\equiv \dbinom72\dbinom52\dbinom31\dbinom21\dbinom11 \equiv \dfrac{7!}{2!2!1!1!1!}$, all forms of the **multinomial coefficient**, which you can view as an extension of the binomial coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You do this in two steps.

1. First choose how many jobs each person gets, with the condition that each person gets at least one job.
2. Assign jobs afterwards.

For example, person A gets 2 jobs, B gets 2 jobs, C gets 2 jobs, and D gets 1 job.

After you made that choice the number of assignments is then ${{7}\choose 2,2,2,1}$.

Now sum all cases from step (1).

Comment: This is what i did. So my approach is correct. Thanks for guidance